# Transaction not created by ethers.js

Tags: transactions, javascript, nft, ethers.js

I have written the following code to try to mint an NFT based on some git repos I saw. The code runs successfully and outputs a transaction hash, but the hash never resolves to anything on Rinkeby Etherscan. What am I doing wrong?

```
const abi = ...

const ethers = require('ethers');

const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider("https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/...");

const wallet = new ethers.Wallet("0x97332958d5acbd80aafc0c7c724e25cc09cca2251b9c38e81dc2442ad7130943", provider);

const contractAddress = "0x95E4fa42CD4f5B6a80ba3ED1ee3aD363dd8Bf7D3";

const contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, abi, wallet);

async function main() {
    var options = { gasPrice: 1000000000, gasLimit: 850000, nonce: 54, value: 0 };
    let txn = await contract.mint(wallet.address, "/", options);
    console.log(txn.hash);
}

main();
```

Answer (score 0):

I just changed `options` to:

`var options = { gasLimit: 850000 };`

And it works now.